# Sort Alphanumeric column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

My data is in this way

```
<400    
1000-1200    
1200-1400    
1400-1600    
1600-1800    
400-600    
600-700    
700-800    
800-1000
```

And I want this way

```
<400    
400-600    
600-700    
700-800    
800-1000    
1000-1200    
1200-1400
...
```

```
 order by   LEFT(WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC])-1), 
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC]), LEN(WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC])))
```

This is the code I have used in SQL Server but its not working

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Column] VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Column])
VALUES ('<400')
      ,('1000-1200')
      ,('1200-1400')
      ,('1400-1600')
      ,('1600-1800')
      ,('400-600')
      ,('600-700')
      ,('700-800')
      ,('800-1000');

SELECT [Column]
      ,TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([Column], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [Column])))
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([Column], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [Column])));
```

[image]

Note, that [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is available after `SQL Server 2012`, so if you are using earlier version you can use `CAST`:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING([Column], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [Column])) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
ORDER BY LEFT(WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC])-1) DESC, 
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC]), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', WC.[WGHT_CLAS_DESC])-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @t table(val varchar(max))
insert into @t
select '<400'
union select '1000-1200'    
union select '1200-1400'    
union select '1400-1600'    
union select '1600-1800'    
union select '400-600'  
union select '600-700'    
union select '700-800'    

SELECT rn=row_number() over( order by StartNumber,EndNumber),StartNumber,EndNumber Val
FROM (
    select  
            CAST(RIGHT(val,LEN(val)-CHARINDEX('-',val)) as int) EndNumber,
            CAST(REPLACE(val,'-'+RIGHT(val,LEN(val)-CHARINDEX('-',val)),'') as int) StartNumber,
            val 
    from (
           SELECT REPLACE(Val,'<','0-') As Val from @t
         ) a
)Data
```

of course, i suggest to use TRY_CONVERT after SQL2012